# Data from two tables in collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models defined as follows:

```
class Comic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :feeds
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comic
  has_many :filters
end

class Filter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

In the filter form I have the following:

```
<%= f.collection_select :feed_id, Feed.all, :id, :url, { :include_blank => "Please select" } %>
```

Assuming there's a `:name` field in my comic model how do I display it along the feed URL in the select?

I'd like the rendered HTML to look something like this:

```
<option value="1">Comic Name - Feed URL</option>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to create a new instance method in the feed class for presenting the comic name along with the feed's url:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base

  def display_text
    "#{comic.name} - #{url}" 
  end

end

<%= f.collection_select :feed_id, Feed.all, :id, :display_text, { :include_blank => "Please select" } %>
```

Comment: And bam! This is why I love Stack Overflow! Thanks!